# About relation between Kostka numbers and Littlewood-Richardson coefficient

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

The fact that Kostka numbers equals to Littlewood-Richardson coefficients for some partitions is already known $\colon$
\begin{align}
   K_{\lambda \mu} = c_{\sigma \lambda}^\tau
\end{align}
where $\tau_i = \mu_{i} + \mu_{i+1} +\cdots, \sigma_i = \mu_{i+1} + \mu_{i+2} + \cdots$.

For example, it is written in 
[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240265470_Stretched_Littlewood-Richardson_and_Kostka_Coefficients), page 3.

But I have not found a proof of this claim.
So if you know paper or book in which this claim's proof is written, then please tell me it. 
If possible I would like to know a proof which construct a bijection between semi-standard tableaux and LR-tableaux.

Comment: That's a good question. There is an excellent answer by R. Stanley to a more general question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116171/skew-kostka-coefficients-from-littlewood-richardson-coefficients

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skew Kostka coefficients from Littlewood-Richardson Coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116171/skew-kostka-coefficients-from-littlewood-richardson-coefficients)

Comment: What do you mean by "$\tau_i = (\mu_{i}, \mu_{i+1},\dots), \sigma_i = (\mu_{i+1}, \mu_{i+2},\dots)$"? Either you're defining partitions or you're defining entries of a partition.

Comment: @ darij grinberg I defined $\tau_i$ and $\sigma_i$ as entries of a prtition, namely Set $\mu = (\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_k)$, then we define $\tau = (\tau_1, \dots, \tau_k)$, $\sigma = (\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_{k-1})$. where $\tau_i = (\mu_i + \mu_{i+1} +\cdots)$, $\sigma_i = (\mu_{i+1} + \mu_{i+2} +\cdots)$.
Thank you for your pointing it out, I have modified the question.

Comment: @Per Alexandersson 
Thank you. The answer is probably what I want to know (I still don't have completely understanding). By the way, is there a bijection proof of this formula ?

Comment: @Timothy Chow
Thank you for you guide. would you know if there is a bijection proof of this formula?

Comment: I believe (9.4) in Macdonald's book, p.143 is something like that - I remember thinking about this a while ago, and I think I found quite an easy bijection...